# Refresh materialized view value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I would need some help to understand the value of the refresh. I want to know the refresh value of the following materialized view.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EXAMPLE_EX

REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT (TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)+9/24)
```

How often it's going to be refreshed?, I don't understand how 9/24 is calculated. I googled it but didn't find a valuable answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date arithmetic in Oracle is such that "1" equals 1 day. So, 9/24 equals 9 hours. This materialized view will refresh each day at 9:00 AM.